# How do i add a CCPhysicsNode In Spritebuilder?

Tags: spritebuilder

Im doing the tutorial and make school (https://www.makeschool.com/academy/tutorial/learn-how-to-build-flappy-bird/let-the-bunny-fall-1d2b5d5e-d0ec-4b78-9570-86128e33f9f1) and i cant add a physics node. I cant find it to drag it in to my game. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In SpriteBuilder, go to MainScene.swift.
Look up in the upper-left corner, below the Publish button. There are 4 little icons, which take you to tabs. One of those is the "nodes" tab.
Once at the "nodes" tab, select the first node, and drag it into your stage(where the blues sky is). It should be positioned in your script underneath clouds, like the pic you see in step 4(at MakeSchool.com).
[screen pic of where to find physics node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRM4d.png)